# Angular : can't display localStorage content

Tags: angular

I want to use user informations in all pages of my site.
So I use LocalStorage to save this data. Like this :

```
  onSubmit() {
this.submitted = true;
if (!this.loginForm.valid) {
  return;
}
this.loading = true;
this.authService.SignIn(this.f.login.value, this.f.password.value)
  .pipe(finalize(() => {
    if(this.loggedUser == null){
      this.router.navigate(['/Login']);
    }
    else{
      this.router.navigate(['/']);
    }
  }))
  .subscribe(response => {
    localStorage.setItem('isLoggedIn',JSON.stringify(this.isLoggedIn)); 
    localStorage.setItem('loggedUser', JSON.stringify(response));        
    this.loggedUser = response as User;
    this.isLoggedIn = true;
    this.authService.setData(response as User);
  }),
  (error) => {
    this.error = error;
    this.loading = false;
    this.errorHandler.handleError(error);
    this.errorMessage = this.errorHandler.errorMessage;
  };
```

}

In another component, I do this to reuse the user informations.

```
this.isLogged = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('isloggedIn') || '{}');
this.user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('loggedUser') || '{}');
```

And in the html page I try top display datas like this :

```
<p>IsLogged : {{isLogged}}</p>
```

User : {{item.username}}

...but it doesn't display anithing.
I don't understand why.
Is there someone who can help me?
Thanks

Comment: Your workflow is a little bit wrong. At first, the sign-in API call should return the token, and in the localStorage you should store only the token. After you should have the guard which should be placed on your secure routes. Also, You need to have another API by which you should be able to get the user information by the token(`from sign-in API`) in case of validity. And your Guard should call that API to get the user information by the token and save it in the singleton service.

Comment: It will fix not only the issue which you have and also a lot of pain connected with security and page refresh

Comment: Hello thanks for your help. I have an asp.net core API as service. I ask informations to my API service once and I want to save that in a gloabal function so I use localStorage. I don't want to ask each time user information to my api service

Comment: My understanding is that you need to check the token/user validity on every page refresh

Comment: I want to be abble to use user informations (name, phone, email...) on each pages of my website. I just want to ask that once to my api and be abble to reuse it on each pages.Not ask them each time.

Comment: Then your code looks good, the only problem which you can have, it can be an asynchronous work of your code

Comment: make sure your `localStorage.getItem(......)` logic is calling after `localStorage.setItem(......)`

Comment: Yes, I think that localStorage.getItem() is called after the localStorage.setItem()

Comment: hmm, then you need to try to log(`console.log()`) step by step to understand what is the sign-in API response, and what you get from the localStorage

Comment: When I do setItem my object has value but when I do JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('isloggedIn') the object is null

Comment: for `isloggedIn` your code is wrong, try `this.isLogged = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('isloggedIn') || 'false');` it shouldn't be Object it should be boolean

Comment: When I put my cursor on localStorage it contains values for isLogged and loggedUser

Comment: oh also your key name is wrong as well it should be `this.isLogged = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('isLoggedIn') || 'false');`

Comment: Great, it's better with isLoggedIn. I have the right value.
I check now for loggedUser

Comment: It's ok, I can display user informations. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: No problem, glad to help!